# Accessible button with tooltip to open a modal

Tags: html, accessibility, bootstrap-5, screen-readers

I have a requirement to make a button that has a tooltip which provides some simple statistical information to a user. (a student's grades for example: "Homework: 100%, Exams: 85%") When the user clicks that same button it should bring up a modal with more detailed information. (Like each assignment's grade for example). I need this to be accessible for screen readers. I am using Bootstrap 5 as a framework. I've seen suggestions that are not ADA compliant for accomplishing this task. What is the best way to do this and have it be accessible?

Answer (score 1):

If the tooltip is only available to mouse users, then that would be an accessibility issue.  A keyboard user should be able to <kbd>tab</kbd> to the button and see the tooltip.

Say what you will about IE but it had a nice built in feature that tooltips (`title=` attribute) were displayed by the browser when the user navigated to the element with the keyboard.  Fortunately, Edge also does this.  Chrome and Firefox do not so you'd have to code this yourself.

Secondly, the tooltip text needs to be programmatically associated with your button so that screen readers can announce the tooltip text.  You *should* get this behavior for "free" because of the "[Accessible Name and Description Computation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2)".

- The "accessible **name**" of the button should come from the button text (step F in the previous link, "name from content").  Eg `<button tooltip="grades">open dialog</button>` will have an accessible name of "open dialog".
- The "accessible **description**" of the button should come from the tooltip (step I ["eye"] in the previous link) if the description can't be found in other attributes (such as `aria-describedby`).  Eg `<button tooltip="grades">open dialog</button>` will have an accessible description of "grades".

When a screen reader user navigates to the button, they will typically hear the accessible name followed by the accessible description (among other info such as the type/role of the element and possibly the state [such as `aria-pressed`]).  So you *shouldn't* have to do anything to get the tooltip read but you'll want to test it in several browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) with various screen readers (JAWS, NVDA, Voiceover).

Note that the screen reader user can turn *off* descriptions so that they'd only hear the accessible name and not hear the tooltip, but that's totally up to the user.  As long as you coded it correctly, you don't have to worry about that scenario.

Comment: Is this an issue though, if the grades are accessible inside the dialog?

Comment: That depends if you're comfortable providing a feature for only some users.  Seeing the tooltip on the button, which has a "mini" set of information from the dialog, allows the user to decide if they want to see **all** the information in the dialog or not. All users should have that ability.  And 2.1.1 starts with "**All functionality** of the content is operable through a keyboard interface..."  If the functionality of the tooltip is not available through the keyboard, it fails 2.1.1.  Now, is it a high priority issue?  It doesn't sound like it in this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

There's no real way to make a tooltip on a button that's accessible, since touchscreen users have no way to trigger it without triggering the button. Tooltips are also confusing, since even mouse users who can trigger a tooltip may not realize there is anything there to trigger.

The best approach in your case is likely to include the information from the tooltip in the modal itself as plain text. (You can keep the tooltip or remove it.)

This will improve the experience for other users too. This "simple statistical information" seems like it would be handy, and having it as part of the modal allows it to be copied (for example), unlike a traditional tooltip.

For constructing the modal itself, I would follow [Bootstrap's example code](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/).